# My li:hover does not react as expected?

Tags: css

[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AeaD9/1/)

The element normally has an underline. I want for that underline to be completely hidden when the mouse is anywhere in the opaque "cloud" that appears when the cursor is over the element.

The underline is applied as a `border-bottom` of the parent div as shown below:

```
.element_style{
    width:98%;
    line-height:40px;
    font-family: 'Lato';
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size:18px;

    /*Order at the bottom*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);   

    position:relative;
}
```

However you will notice that if you go down slowly in the element, to just below where the underline should be, you will notice the underline appear again like so [image]

I was unable to fix this behaviour, how can I approach going about doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove the border from the .element_style element when you hover over the (parent)  .unremovable element.

So do this:

```
.unremovable:hover .element_style{
    border:none;
}
```

**[Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AeaD9/8/)**